# the kde pin button API

Tags: c++, c, x11, kde-plasma

You have probably already noticed the pin button of KDE, that pins a window across multiple virtual desktops. I would like to know what API the pin button functionality is part of, is it X or KDE or something else? The pin button is second from the left in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On KDE SC 4.x ut is part of the `kwin` API.  It is [KWin::Workspace::slotWindowOnAllDesktops](http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/kdebase-workspace-apidocs/kwin/html/classKWin_1_1Workspace.html#a77b24984de50b443ebc73ba0788638e0).  It is also available through the `kwin` javascript scripting api as [slotWindowOnAllDesktops()](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/Scripting/API_4.9#Functions_2)

On KDE Frameworks 5 it is part of the `KWindowSystem` API.  Specifically it is [KWindowSystem::setOnAllDesktops](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kwindowsystem/html/classKWindowSystem.html#a3dfdfbe26d5bb59dd34ade9afa4d3971)